# Windows 10 slowdown and extremely long boot time

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, performance

Yesterday a HP ProBook laptop was running fine, with 8GB RAM and Intel Core i7-6500U 2.5GHz CPU.

Today morning, the Windows 10 machine was **extremely slow**. Windows task bar was not responding. Using some OS features line network manager wasn’t possible. So decided to reboot the machine. After rebooting, the windows got stuck at the loading page.

1. I hard-reset the machine, and used diagnostic tools, but they didn’t show any problem.
2. Pressing F8 at boot time, i.e. safe mode, led to automatic repair, which would eventually end up in a blank/black screen.
3. Finally, I rebooted again and waited so long for Windows loading to finish. After some long minutes finally Windows showed login page.

The Windows is still slow, but it is unstable.  Opening an application might take more than 2 minutes, maybe 3 or 4 minutes.

This is NOT the first time I run into such slowdowns. I wonder whether this behavior is occasionally expected? How can I prevent such slowdowns?

---

Laptop has HDD:

[image: C:\ drive]

### UPDATE

Two days later:

[image: Blue screen]

Suddenly, I run into the blue screen. I wait long but it is stuck at `0% Complete`. I restart manually. Restart takes maybe 15 to 20 minutes. Then I receive a login screen with no input field for password! I restart again, this time it's faster. I get a login screen WITH a password field. I login and opening any application takes 2 to 3 minutes.

As suggested by the accepted answer, probably I'm going to totally replace this OS =(

### UPDATE

It is more than one month since I reinstalled Windows 10 and deleted all the old partitions which were MBR-based and created new GPT partitions. During this period, the new Windows 10 is responsive. I'm satisfied so far :)

Comment: Is the disk full or almost full? Do you have an SSD or HDD?

Comment: @gronostaj I have HDD with 74 GB free of 459 GB

Comment: Have you checked to see whether or not one of your RAM modules was accidentally disconnected?

Comment: Run `chkdsk` and check the SMART data of the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Task Manager: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>

- On the `Details` tab, order by CPU or I/O usage to see if some process is using up resources. (Right-click on the column headers to add `I/O read bytes` and `I/O write bytes` if need be.)
- Click on the `Startup` tab to see if some process has impact during boot.
- Check for malware with an additional AV tool, such as [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) or from a boot disk, e.g. [Kaspersky Rescue Disk](https://usa.kaspersky.com/downloads/thank-you/free-rescue-disk).
- Also check if you the internet is a bottleneck. If your PC is syncing large amounts of data with OneDrive, Adobe Creative Cloud and other online services, then that could slow responsiveness. Temporarily disconnect (e.g. Airplane mode or unplug Ethernet) to see if the PC behaves better.

Also try running an alternative OS from a USB flash drive, such as [Ubuntu](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/). If that works well, then you know the issue is in Windows or the SSD. You can test the SSD from BIOS or from the alternative OS.

If Windows *is* the culprit, reinstall from the [Windows ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) (or, if the alternative OS works better, install that instead).

Comment: Thanks =) I uploaded the task manager screenshots [here](https://imgur.com/a/XCebUzO). I looked at it, but I'm not sure if anything is suspicious.

Comment: Downloaded and installed Malwarebytes too. It's scanning now.

Comment: Your screenshots show nothing unusual about CPU usage... on one shot, 80% of the time the CPU is idle... loafing! However, you use a number of "cloud services", such as OneDrive and Adobe CS. The issue could be that your PC is constantly communicating with the network, and waiting for replies, to sync data.

Comment: Thanks! Surprisingly, as far as I remember, I didn't sign up for any Adobe cloud! I'm going to see how can I uninstall or disable Adobe cloud =)

Comment: I'm writing this comment while using a live USB of Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and the computer is really responsive. It works great during about 10 minutes of trial.